# kafka on kubernetes ingress host based

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am using confluent operator for confluent kafka on kubernetes. I am trying to setup a host based access to the confluent platform components, namely schema registry and rest proxy. Confluent has several examples on github but I find it far from comprehensive. The ingress controller for a platform is as

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-with-sni
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - kafka.$DOMAIN
        - b0.$DOMAIN
        - b1.$DOMAIN
        - b2.$DOMAIN
        - controlcenter.$DOMAIN
        - ksqldb.$DOMAIN
        - connect.$DOMAIN
  rules:
    - host: kafka.$DOMAIN
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: kafka-bootstrap
              servicePort: 9092
    - host: b0.$DOMAIN
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: kafka-0-internal
              servicePort: 9092
    - host: b1.$DOMAIN
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: kafka-1-internal
              servicePort: 9092
    - host: b2.$DOMAIN
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: kafka-2-internal
              servicePort: 9092
    - host: controlcenter.$DOMAIN
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: controlcenter-0-internal
              servicePort: 9021
    - host: ksqldb.$DOMAIN
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: ksqldb-bootstrap
              servicePort: 8088
    - host: connect.$DOMAIN
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: connect-bootstrap
              servicePort: 8083
```

connect, ksqldb and kafka have a bootstrap service represented within the backed endpoints, I assume this is because there are multiple replicas of these components from what I assume that if I have a single replica of schema registry I could just add:

```
- host: schemaregistry.$DOMAIN
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              serviceName: schemaregistry-0-internal
              servicePort: 8081
```

and addind the schemaregistry to hosts array would open for ingress towards the schema registry. I suppose the same shall be done for rest proxy if I want to access it externally. Am I right in this? Trying it I cannot connect, but that could be the VPN setup...

Also one thing that makes me wonder is the specification of protocol as "http" for the individual brokers, I would expect this to be plain "TCP" as kafka wire runs over TCP. Is this just how we force nginx to route TCP? Does not seem right.

Comment: Please read https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/

Answer (score 0):

The rest proxy issue turned out to be a VPN problem indeed and the UDP and TCP routing is explained very well in the https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/ as mentioned in the comment.